# ASP.NET automatically setting horizontal scrollbar centered

Tags: asp.net, scrollbar

I'm using VS2010,C# to develop an ASP.NET web app, my page contains a wide image, so that users will usually see a horizontal scrollbar, but I want this scroll bar to be automatically placed centered horizontally so that my user always views the image and the whole screen in center by default, is there any way to do so?

thanks

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/eliminate-jumps-in-horizontal-centering-by-forcing-a-scroll-bar/ see if this Fulfills your requirement

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid');  //or however you get a handle to the IMG 
var width = img.clientWidth; 
var height = img.clientHeight; 

// Jquery
$("div.demo").scrollLeft(width/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this... you would need to create custom script for your scroll bar

[Custom Scroll Bar](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/rangeinput/scrollbar.html)